libinput example program doesn't get any events
https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/api/index.html
Following the simple example program in their website i made the following , but the loop never executes , meaning no events where in the queue.
Am i missing something ?
Since this is the example in the website i expected it to work , or atleast enter the loop.


#include <cassert>
#include <cerrno>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <libinput.h>
#include <libudev.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int open_restricted(const char *path, int flags, void *user_data) {
  int fd = open(path, flags);
  return fd < 0 ? -errno : fd;
}

static void close_restricted(int fd, void *user_data) { close(fd); }

const static struct libinput_interface interface = {
    .open_restricted = open_restricted,
    .close_restricted = close_restricted,
};

int main(void) {
  struct libinput *li;
  struct libinput_event *event;
  struct udev *udev_ctx = udev_new();
  assert(udev_ctx && "udev was null");

  li = libinput_udev_create_context(&interface, NULL, udev_ctx);
  assert(li != NULL && "li was null");
  libinput_udev_assign_seat(li, "seat0");
  libinput_dispatch(li);

  printf("Hello");

  while ((event = libinput_get_event(li)) != NULL) {

    printf("loop");
    // handle the event here

    libinput_event_destroy(event);
    libinput_dispatch(li);
  }

  libinput_unref(li);

  return 0;
}


system info:
 - system: `"x86_64-linux"`
 - host os: `Linux 6.6.31, NixOS, 24.05 (Uakari), 24.05.20240521.5710852`
 - multi-user?: `no`
 - sandbox: `yes`
 - version: `nix-env (Nix) 2.18.2`
 - channels(root): `"nixos-23.05"`
 - nixpkgs: `not found`
--------

❯ libinput --version
1.25.0
--------

❯ systemctl --version
systemd 255 (255.6)
+PAM +AUDIT -SELINUX +APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT -GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 +PWQUALITY +P11KIT +QRENCODE +TPM2 +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD +BPF_FRAMEWORK -XKBCOMMON +UTMP -SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified


Build with :
gcc -o test main.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs libinput` ` pkg-config --cflags --libs libudev`


Try running it with root privileges.
To be able to run it without root privileges you have to either

add yourself to the input group and have appropriate udev rules configured (I don't recommend doing that)
or preferably use something like libseat to implement your open_restricted and close_restricted functions

